# Why isn't there any clipping in this diode circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, voltage-clipping

This is the circuit.

[image]

This the input and output graph:

[image]

Comment: What output did you expect to get?

Comment: The diode can in this case be treated as an open circuit so it's effectively a voltage divider with two equal resistors.

Comment: The diode basically stops V2 from ever pushing current out of itself against V1 so V2 can never influence the output. All V2 can do is sit around and wait for V1 to push current through itself and be overpowered.

Comment: @Carl but the diode would be forward biased when the input value becomes greater than 5.6, right?

Comment: @G36 I was expecting a clipped output

Comment: What I am thinking is that when the diode is reverse-biased the circuit behaves as a voltage divider, and when the input is > 5.6 V, the output will be 5.6V.

Comment: But the input voltage is too low, so the diode is reverse-biased all the time. You need Vin to be larger than 5.6V*(1 + R1/R2) = 11.2V

Comment: To see why, remove the diode entirely: you'll get the same result. Now you can see why the diode never conducts: because its anode never reaches 5.6V.

Comment: The current through R1 is always >= the current through R2. Therefore the voltage at the anode is always <= half of V1. Try increasing the amplitude of V1.

Comment: " but the diode would be forward biased when the input value becomes greater than 5.6, right?" Right. but you have a 10-volt pk-pk sine wave, which means its maximum voltage is 5 volts. Try changing your sine wave spec to 0 20 1000 and see what happens.

Comment: You have a circuit simulator... it would have been the most trivial thing in the world to experiment with varying the voltage V2, and also the amplitude of V1, and seeing what happens. Why haven't you done that? It should have been the first thing to do even before asking any questions. You have to play with the circuit and see how it reacts to changes in operating parameters. Otherwise you just stare at static pictures and try to guess. You need to gain the intuition about such things *somehow*, and "playing with knobs" on safe circuits is a good place to start!

Answer (score 2):

From the comments:

> but the diode would be forward biased when the input value becomes greater than 5.6, right?

**Assumption: The diode is forward biased**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQz9Nf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the diode is forward biased (and is silicon), then \$V_a-V_3=0.7\text{V} \Rightarrow V_a = 5.7\text{V} \$. The current running through \$R_2 \$ is
$$I_2 = \frac{V_a}{R_2} = \frac{5.7\text{V}}{10\text{k}\Omega} = 0.57\text{mA} $$
Let's consider when the input is at max value \$V_{in} = 10\text{V} \$ the current through \$R_1 \$ is
$$I_1 = \frac{V_{in}-V_a}{R_1}=\frac{10\text{V}-5.7\text{V}}{10\text{k}\Omega} = 0.43\text{mA} $$
So 0.57mA flows out of node a, while only 0.43mA flows in? The remaining \$0.57\text{mA}-0.43\text{mA}=0.14\text{mA} \$ must come from somewhere, and that can only be from the diode branch... BUT current **cannot** flow from the cathode to the anode of the diode.

We arrive at a **contradiction** and the diode must be reversed biased. Moreover, we considered this when \$V_{in} \$ was maximum so it can be concluded that the diode is off **for all cases**. Hence the circuit is always a voltage divider.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwYQWe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Equivalent circuits. R1 and R2 form a 2:1 potential divider so V<sub>a</sub> can never exceed 5 V. The Thevenin equivalent voltage source is a 5 V peak with 5 kΩ source resistance.*

The rearrangement of R1 and R2 into R3 and R4 should make the potential divider clear.

As shown by the equivalent circuits, D1, D2 and D3 are never forward biased so the DC supply never sinks any current and has no affect on V<sub>a</sub>.

Answer (score 0):

For positive excursions of V1, the current through R1 includes the diode current and the current through R2. Therefore the voltage drop across R2 is <= the voltage drop across R1.

Thus, the voltage at the anode is always <= half of V1.

If you increase the amplitude of V1 beyond 10V you will start to see clipping.